# PowerShell calculated properties and $_ placeholder empty output with foreach command

Tags: powershell, foreach, properties, placeholder

I am trying to put the Port used with the command "Get-VersionInfo" in the table. Using PowerShell and I cannot figure out how to output this placeholder in a calculated property. If I stop it and debug, I can put my mouse over "$_.Port" and it says "Port = 50003" So I know it sees what port it is, but when it is outputted to the table it is blank.
Script:

```
    Get-Content "C:\Users\textfile" | Foreach ` {
Get-VersionInfo -Device 10.247.46.123 -Port $_ |
Select-Object IPAddress, Category, Prompt, Hostname, MACAddress, VersionOS, @{l="Port";e={ $_.Port}} | Format-table -autosize
}
```

Output:

```
    IPAddress    Category       Prompt  Hostname        MACAddress        VersionOS        Port
    ---------    --------       ------  --------        ----------        ---------        ---- 
169.254.40.2 Control System DMB-I-S DMB-I-S--548190 00.10.7F.54.81.90 1.501.2964.38161
```

Thanks!

Comment: The formatting around port as a select-object property is strange, I have never seen it before. What are you trying to achieve, specifically with this bit of code?

Comment: The devices are Audio/Video equipment and the commands are provided by the manufacturer in a custom module. I just need to figure out how to put the text (port) used from the text file in that specific for-each command and output it into the table

Comment: @MaximeFranchot it's a ["calculated property"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx). the `l` is short for Label and the `e` for Expression, and it's a short way to dynamically add a property in the select-object list, taking values from the pipeline instead of doing a whole `foreach-object { $_ | add-member ... }`.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler That's interesting, thank you for the explanation. Ironically, my first instinct was to recommend using a `foreach-object{..}` statement (`%{...}`). Perhaps this is the better way, but I am not familiar enough with it to be able to help :(

Comment: @MichaelJohnson I think the syntax looks right; but why are you doing it at all? If `$_.Port` is a thing, `Select-Object [..] VersionOS, Port` would work, right? I can only guess you're trying to get the value of the `$_` from the parent scope (the foreach loop)  - the text file line - but that doesn't have a .Port property and shouldn't show up in the debugger, so.. ??? Maybe try `Get-VersionInfo | foreach { $_.Port.GetType() ; $_ | Get-Member }` to try and see whether port is a property or if the name is slightly different, and if it's an integer or not.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to pass the foreach object.

```
$Ver = Foreach ($Port in Get-Content C:\Script\Port.txt) 
{ Get-VersionInfo -Device 10.10.10.10 -Port $Port |
Where-Object {$_.Ping -eq 'True'} |
Select-Object IPAddress, Category, Prompt, Hostname, Serial, MACAddress, VersionOS, @{l="Port";e={$Port}}, Build, Ping, TSID 
}
```

Hopefully this can help someone else. Thanks guys